# jQuery: Check several inputs, and enable/disable submit button on changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to display several values which are coming from my database on input boxes, which come pre-filled in on page load. The user can change those values, and only when the values are changed and different, does the Submit button become enabled.

Here is a picture for clarity:

[image]

As you can see, the Submit button is disabled.

Here is my jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let originalStart = $('#algorithmStart').val();
    let originalStop = $('#algorithmStop').val();
    let originalAlgorithm = $('#algorithmSelect').val();
    let originalResultName = $('#resultName').val()

    // Detect changes to the baseline parameters    
    $('.checkChanges').change(function() {                                                      
        var thisVal = $(this).val();

        // Enable submit button if the parameters are changed
        if ($.inArray(thisVal, [originalStart, originalStop, originalAlgorithm, originalResultName]) == -1) {
            $('#submitChanges').removeAttr('disabled');                                         
        } else {
            $('#submitChanges').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

All input elements have a class of **checkChanges**, so that on **change()**, the function runs, compares the new value to the original values through **$.inArray()**, and enables the button if they are different.

The problem is if I change more than 1 value, the button is enabled, as it should, but then if I go back to the original value on just ONE of those inputs, the button becomes disabled again, even though there are still values which are different.

For example, changing the start from 20 to 200, and the stop from 500 to 5000, enables the button, which is correct, but if I change the start from 200 back to 20, the button grays out again, even though stop is still 5000 and different from the original value.

I was thinking about using **each()** along with **change()**, but I can't chain them correctly, IE:

```
$('.checkChanges').each().change(function() { //... });
```

Doesn't work. How would I go about doing this without writing several check cases for each input that compare against each original value?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compare the value it has with the value that it had on page load to see if it is different.

```js
var $elements = $('.checkChanges');

$elements.on('change', function() {
  if ($elements.filter(function(){ return this.value != this.getAttribute('value'); }).length) {
    $('#submitChanges').removeAttr('disabled');  
  } else {
    $('#submitChanges').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="checkChanges" value="test1">
<input type="text" class="checkChanges" value="test2">
<button id="submitChanges" disabled>Weee</button>
```

Comment: It's weird, I see the snippet and it does exactly what I need, but using your code on my page doesn't give me the same functionality. The class  names are the same. The only difference I can see is I'm using jQuery 3.2.1.min. Could that be it? [EDIT]: Just tried with that same jQuery version and it didn't work the same either. When I change 2 values, the button is enabled, but going back to the original values doesn't disable it again.

Comment: Updated snippet to use v3.3.1